# What causes Rigidbody character to suddenly move at fast speeds?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody

I'm trying to make a Rigidbody-based movement script for a character.
It behaves pretty much as expected, but every once in a while the character will suddenly run at a massive speed. I can't find a pattern as to what movement causes it.

What might be flawed about the logic here that is causing unexpected speed behavior? My project's gravity is set to -75 if that matters.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveGuy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody _rigidBody;
    public bool _isGrounded = true;
    public bool _isSprinting = false;

    //Base Movement
    private Vector3 movDirection;
    public float _baseMaxSpeed = 15f;
    public float _baseMoveForce = 100f;
    public float _stopSlideSpeed = 1f;

    //Ground Check
    public bool _shouldCheckGround = true;
    public Transform _groundCheckTransform;
    public float _groundCheckRadius = 0.25f;
    public LayerMask _groundLayerMask;

    //Sprinting
    public bool _allowSprinting = true;
    public float _sprintMaxSpeed = 20f;
    public float _sprintMoveForce = 150f;

    //Jump
    public bool _allowJumping = true;
    public float _jumpForce = 25f;

   


    void Awake()
    {
        _rigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Sprinting();
        }

    }

    public void Move()
    {
        // check to see if we are sliding too much and stop movement        
        if (_rigidBody.velocity.magnitude <= _stopSlideSpeed && movDirection == Vector3.zero)
            _rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;

        // adjusts for max speeds
        float speedFactor = (_baseMaxSpeed - _rigidBody.velocity.magnitude) / _baseMaxSpeed;
        movDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        _rigidBody.AddForce(speedFactor * _baseMoveForce * movDirection, ForceMode.Force);
    }
    public void PhysicsChecks()
    {
        // Ground Check
        if (_shouldCheckGround)
            GroundCheck();
    }

    public void GroundCheck()
    {
        _isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(_groundCheckTransform.position, _groundCheckRadius, _groundLayerMask);
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {        
        Move();
        PhysicsChecks();
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (_allowJumping && _isGrounded)
        {
            _rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, _jumpForce, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }

    void Sprinting()
    {
        if (_allowSprinting && _isGrounded)
        {
            _isSprinting = true;
            _baseMaxSpeed = _sprintMaxSpeed;
            _baseMoveForce = _sprintMoveForce;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks innocuous at first glance (you have a `rigidbody.velocity = ` in there, but it just sets the velocity to 0 so it's *probably* harmless). But weird physics glitches with Unity rigidbody are often the result of multiple rigidbodies interacting in unexpected ways. So I am afraid that looking at just this script in isolation will probably not show us the real reason for this glitch.

Comment: What happens if you remove functionality like `Dash`, `Jump`, `Sprinting` and `Jump` from the script? Do you still experience those problems when you only have the regular movement?

Comment: After removing those functionalities, I could no longer replicate the issue. I added Jump in and still could not. Then when I added Sprint in, I eventually was able to replicate it. Also it looks like my code doesn't allow `IsSprinting` to turn false. So it's gotta most likely be something there. Looking into it more!

Comment: Please update your question with the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. Should you be able to solve the problem on your own, then please write an own answer to your question so nobody else invests time into solving it.

Comment: As @Philipp said, perhaps the glitch is caused by rigidbodies interactions. If it occurs after collisions, try and check the weight of each rigidbody, maybe your rigidbody is colliding with something with much higher mass?